# Apache Camel - Empty body inside AggregationStrategy

Tags: java, apache, split, apache-camel, aggregate

Here is my route:

```
def.convertBodyTo(String.class).split()
                    .method(splittingProcessor, "split")
                    .aggregationStrategy(myAggregationStrategy)
                    .bean(myProcessor, "aMethod")
                    .end();
```

I am trying to send one exchange to more than two different HTTP endpoints.

Here is my aggregation strategy:

```
    @Override 
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) { 
    Message inMsg = newExchange.getIn();
    String body = inMsg.getBody(String.class);

    String oldBody= "";
    if (oldExchange == null) {
        return newExchange;
    }
    else {
        oldBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        oldExchange.getIn().setBody(oldBody + " "+body);
        return oldExchange;
    }
}
```

but

body is always equal to "" and inMsg is "[Body is instance of java.io.InputStream]"

convertBodyTo(String.class) does not work either (at least the way I am using it).

What am I doing wrong?

PS. streamCaching() on the route or setStreamCache(true) on the context also do not work.

**EDIT 1:**

Camel Version: 2.12.13

In aMethod I am using a ProducerTemplate to send the exchange to an HTTP Endpoint:

```
    exchange = producerTemplate.send(uri, exchange);
```

and after that I do some processing to the exchange body.

I have noticed that the same thing works if I use the direct component.

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?, and what do you do in the aMethod of your myProcessor

Comment: Please see my edit #1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is reported in this Camel ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7787

As a workaround for this bug, you use a custom processor, then you can just convert the message body to a String there, so the stream is read into memory and can be safely used in the aggregation strategy.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Where does this processor shall be put? I tried to put it after .bean(myProcessor, "aMethod").process(readBodyToStringProcessor) and read it with IOUtils but the body is still showing empty. (Also tried with convertBodyTo before the split and with streamCaching but nothing seems to do the job)